# Error trying to read json code

Tags: json

Here is my json String:

```
String json = "{\"forms\":[{\"url\":\"https:\/\/pokeapi.co\/api\/v2\/pokemon-form\/1\/\",\"name\":\"bulbasaur\"}]}"
```

However, when I do this:

```
JSONObject root = new JSONObject(json);
```

I get this error:

```
org.json.JSONException: Expected literal value at character 1 of {\"forms\":[{\"url\":\"https:\/\/pokeapi.co\/api\/v2\/pokemon-form\/1\/\",\"name\":\"bulbasaur\"}]}
```

Help?

Comment: In Java, the '/' character doesn't need to be escaped! Try removing the "\/" parts in your json text.

Comment: When using following code, I was unable to reproduce your Error:

`String json = "{\"forms\":[{\"url\":\"https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon-form/1/\",\"name\":\"bulbasaur\"}]}";
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(json);
System.out.println(obj.toString(4));`